# How do I use .gitignore in visual studio code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

So I know this might sound like a noob question but I'm rather inexperienced with GitHub. I want to add a gitignore file to my repository, but I am unable to do so and I don't know how. I want to make sure a file is gitignored My visual studio code is connected with my repository. So I am able to push and pull via visual code.

Greetings,

Parsa & Liyam

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may go to File > New File at the root of your git repository (same directory as where your .git hidden folder is in). Then add all the directories/file that you want to be ignored into that new file and save it as `.gitignore`. (You can `save as` a plaintext file and just name it `.gitignore` within VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for simple explantation. The VSCode Docu confuses about that.

Answer (score 6):

Vscode 1.46 is adding some automated help in generating a `.gitignore` file when you publish to github.  From [v1.46 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#publish-to-github-generate-gitignore):

> #### Publish to Github: Generate .gitignore
>
> It's now possible to generate a `.gitignore` file when publishing a
>   workspace to GitHub. When publishing a workspace to GitHub, you are
>   prompted to select which files to include in the repository.

[image: generate a .gitignore file]

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on your Visual Studio Code and then search for gitignore. Click the add gitignore option then you are good to go.

Comment: what extension are you using? this doesnt work.